# How do you add a Collider2D to a Line Renderer In Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am currently working on a project where you draw using a line renderer. I need to be a to have collisions for my idea to work. I have looked all over the internet but yet nothing has seemed to work. I have provided the code bellow. Thank you for your time.

````
    public Camera m_camera;
    public GameObject brush;

    LineRenderer currentLineRenderer;

    Vector2 lastPos;

    private void Update()
    {
        Drawing();
    }

    void Drawing() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            CreateBrush();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            PointToMousePos();
        }
        else 
        {
            currentLineRenderer = null;
        }
    }

    void CreateBrush() 
    {
        GameObject brushInstance = Instantiate(brush);
        currentLineRenderer = brushInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        //because you gotta have 2 points to start a line renderer, 
        Vector2 mousePos = m_camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, mousePos);
        currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, mousePos);

    }

    void AddAPoint(Vector2 pointPos) 
    {
        currentLineRenderer.positionCount++;
        int positionIndex = currentLineRenderer.positionCount - 1;
        currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(positionIndex, pointPos);
    }

    void PointToMousePos() 
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = m_camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (lastPos != mousePos) 
        {
            AddAPoint(mousePos);
            lastPos = mousePos;
        }
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is bake the mesh from the line renderer.
Use the baked mesh as the mesh for your collider.

You will need to add a mesh collider to some object.  As an example below I added it to your current line renderers gameObject.

```
var mesh = new Mesh();
var meshCollider = currentLineRenderer.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

currentLineRenderer.BakeMesh(mesh, true);
meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
```

[Bake Mesh reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html)

I havent tried this with the polygon collider, I imagine it should still work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but i keep getting a *sigh*, null reference.

Comment: the line I get the error for is 

```var meshCollider = currentLineRenderer.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();```

Comment: maybe the line renderer is null.  I see a place in Drawing where you set to null.  Instead try creating a new GameObject("LR Mesh") and add the polygon collider to that.  My answer has MeshCollider instead of PolygonCollider, try changing that as well.

Comment: for the second part of your fix, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: .AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();  Though i am not sure how that would work with the mesh.  I have never actually used that collider, and it does not seem to have a mesh you can assign..  Try with the MeshCollider first and see if that works.